# Site Won't Show Facebook Like Button in IE WITH fb HTML Attributes

Tags: html, web, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. I've been searching around and been trying to fix this for weeks now, but to no avail.

My Wordpress site refuses to show my facebook like buttons in IE. Yes, I have put the facebook HTML attributes in the code and still nothing. I have two instances I've been trying with the Like button and that is a Wordpress widget (Simple Facebook Connect) as well as the HTML code. This is the first time I've ever had a problem like this on one of my sites and I just need some dire help before this company goes live. Again, any help would be greatly appreciated. The code is listed below.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]><html class="ie ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--><html <?php language_attributes(); ?> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
```

Like Button code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=546891755321471";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/livecarepc" send="false" layout="standard' width="200" show_faces="true" colorscheme="dark"></fb:like>
```

Thank you!

Comment: What version of IE? Any JavaScript errors? You could try explicitly setting `language="JavaScript"` on your `<script>` tag... ahh, IE :)

Comment: Thank you SOOO MUCH!!! That fixed it!! lol you have no idea how happy I am.

Comment: great, I'll post it as the answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer can be very particular about having the correct type information set (doctype, css, scripts, etc). In this case the `<script>` tag is not enough to trigger IE to show the Facebook like button, which is likely to be especially true in older version of IE.

To fix replace `<script>` with `<script language="JavaScript">` in the Like button code.